# How do we get the coefficients and intercept in Logistic Regression?

Tags: logistic-regression

I'm using Codecademy to learn about logistic regression and there are some holes in my understanding of this topic.

```
import numpy as np

hours_studied = np.array([[ 0],[ 1],[ 2],[ 3],[ 4],[ 5],[ 6],[ 7],[ 8],[ 9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19]])
calculated_coefficients = np.array([[0.20678491]])
intercept = np.array([-1.76125712])

def log_odds(features, coefficients,intercept):
  return np.dot(features,coefficients) + intercept
# z = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + ....
# log odds measures how likely it is that the data sample belongs to the positive class

def sigmoid(z):
    denominator = 1 + np.exp(-z)
    return 1/denominator
## In order to map predicted values to probabilities, we use the sigmoid function. 
# The function maps any real value into another value between 0 and 1. 
# In machine learning, we use sigmoid to map predictions to probabilities

# Create predict_class() function here
# features = matrix
# coefficients = vector
def predict_class(features, coefficients, intercept, threshold):
  calculated_log_odds = log_odds(hours_studied, calculated_coefficients, intercept)
  probabilities = sigmoid(calculated_log_odds)
  return np.where(probabilities >= threshold, 1, 0)
# If a value in array_to_check is above threshold, the output is 1. If a value in array_to_check is below threshold, the output is 0.

# Make final classifications on Codecademy University data here
final_results = predict_class(hours_studied, calculated_coefficients, intercept, .5)
print(final_results)
```

hours_studied, calculated_coefficients and intercept were given by codecademy.

I'm not sure how to get these inputs myself to plug into the model and codecademy didn't explain either. Hours_studied I understand.

Maybe could someone help explain what are the possible steps before I define log_odds, sigmoid, etc to get coefficients and intercept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe this part of the code is trying to teach you activities post ML training i.e. prediction*

The coefficient and intercept are the parameters of the Model. These are determined by using *Training data (Features and Labels) and training process*

You follow these steps(*Very high level*) -

 *Get data - X , Y

 Define model i.e. Logistics Regression

 Train Model using the data - Here you get the Coef/Intercept

 Predict using the Model*

In your work, you are at the last step.

 You have a model ready with the parameters and you also got the data *i.e. Features(X)*

 It is as good as calling a function *i.e. get_answer(x)* and get_answer is your model with it's parameters.

Then you say

*if answer > THRESOLD(normally 0.5 but we get the best by trials) it's Class-A else it's Class-B*

You may learn Logistics regression from scratch form [*Blog-machinelearningmastery*](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-logistic-regression-stochastic-gradient-descent-scratch-python/)